# JSONEncoder to turn numbers into Scientific Notation

Tags: python, json, floating-point, integer

I've been trying to encode a dictionary into a pretty string for display purposes and can't figure out why the json.dumps() encoder doesn't work the way I was expecting. I have a custom encoder class,

```py
class ScientificNotationNumbers(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(obj, (int, float)):
            return "{:.2e}".format(obj)
        return super().default(obj)
```

but I reckon that the class is only called when the json package function doesn't recognize the type, and in this case int and floats already have a serialization method. Any way to overload just these two types in order for me to represent the numbers as scientific notation directly from the `json.dumps()` function?

Note: This is being used as:

```py
def __str__(self) -> String:
    return json.dumps(self, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, cls=ScientificNotationNumbers)
```